# Syslog log analyzer

Tags: syslog

Is there any syslog log analyzer script I can install on hosting to track user activity?
I have giant user log and I need more specific log details.

Comment: Checkout: http://www.syslog.org/wiki/Main/LogAnalyzers

Answer (score 0):

Many Linux distributions provide [logcheck](http://logcheck.org/), which can be easily configured to analyse syslog and provide periodic reports of log activity through email.  It is simple to use and very powerful.

Most distributions provide a basic configuration which report known problems and user activity, and a cron task that will send these reports through e-mail.